# REST API and extended service in paths

Tags: cloudify

When i deploy with REST API i receive the following error.

> 'Failed to set extent: could not find extended service in paths'.

I have resolve with Tomcat `(replace extend "../../../services/tomcat" with extend "tomcat")` but i have problem with MySql.

Answer (score 0):

This probably occurs because mysql doesn't come with the Cloudify 2.7* distribution zip file.

You need to download (e.g. : git clone https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes.git) and then place the mysql service and specify its relative path in the command.

HTH,
Tamir,